# Fubini and Tonelli's Theorems - integrability and nonnegativity condition

Tags: real-analysis, integration

What I understand about these two theorems is that (simply speaking)

a) (Fubini) if the integrant $f$ is integrable, then its interated integral is interchangeable

b) (Tonelli) if the integrant $f$ is measurable and nonnegative, then its interated integral is interchangeable

My question is that if I can prove that $f$ is integrable or $\int|f|$ is finite (so that I could apply Fubini), can I say that $f$ is also nonnegative? or vice versa?

p.s. I am trying to prove something is nonnegative but couldn't find a way, but I noticed that it was used in Fubini and we proved its integrability.

Comment: why would a general integrable function have to be nonnegative?

Comment: $f$ non-negative does not imply that $f$ is integrable and $f$ is integrable does not imply that $f$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no". A better answer is that you don't need to do this.

Say $f(x,y)$ is a function defined on some product measure space. Then $|f|$ is non-negative. So you can apply Tonelli; if $\int_X\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,dxdy<\infty$ then $f$ is integrable and so you can then apply Fubini.

This is a very standard thing, applying Tonelli to show that Fubini is applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess my main aim here is to prove $f$ is nonnegative (which I couldn't so far) since I need its nonnegativity in the rest of my analysis... But I noticed that we have already proved its integrability for Fubini so I wondered whether there is a connection for me to prove its nonnegativity here

Comment: @FDS Why not ask the question you actually want an answer to? Fubini and Tonelli have very little to do with showing that $f\ge0$...